# Howto add tooltip to rows of rich:dataTable (RIchfaces 4)

Tags: richfaces

Is it possible to add a tooltip to an entire row of a `rich:dataTable`?
I think this a very common use case, but we could not get it to work as expected. What we currently use is a tooltip per table cell. This works, but is drastically increases the amount of transferred data: If the table has 15 rows and 11 columns this results in 165 tooltips...

The code looks like this:

```
<rich:dataTable id="artikelListTable" rowClasses="oddRow, evenRow"  rows="15"
    value="#{artikelListeController.artikelListe}" var="artikel">

    <rich:column id="laufendeNummer" sortBy="#{artikel.laufendeNummer}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText
                 value="#{messages['devA.articlelist.laufendeNummer']}" />
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="#{artikel.laufendeNummer}">
            <f:convertNumber pattern="00000" />
        </h:outputText>

        <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/pages/articlelist/article_tooltip.xhtml" />
     </rich:column>

     <rich:column id="status" headerClass="statusColumn">
         <f:facet name="header">
             <h:outputText value="#{messages['devA.articlelist.status']}" />
         </f:facet>

         <div align="center">
             <h:graphicImage styleClass="statusImage"
                  value="../../resources/images/ampel/#{artikel.ampelStatus.name}.png"/>
         </div>

         <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/pages/articlelist/article_tooltip.xhtml" />
      </rich:column>
      ........

      <f:facet name="footer">
          <rich:dataScroller for="artikelListTable" fastControls="hide" />
      </f:facet>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Richfaces developers guide, [rich:tooltip](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Output_and_messages.html#sect-Component_Reference-Output_and_messages-richtooltip) "can be attached to any control and is displayed when hovering the mouse cursor over the control". So, you can place your `h:outputText`  inside `rich:panel` and add tool tip for it. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've played around a bit with RF-4.3 and it appears that `rich:dataTable` has nice `onrowmouseover` and `onrowmouseout` events that we can leverage for this. Here's how I implemented it:

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{dataBean.data}" var="datum"
    onrowmouseover="if (jQuery(event.target).parents('.warn').length !== 0) #{rich:component('multiWarning')}.show(event);"
    onrowmouseout="#{rich:component('multiWarning')}.hide();">

    <rich:column styleClass="#{dataBean.needWarn(datum) != null ? 'warn' : ''}">
        <h:outputText value="#{datum.toString()}" />
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
<rich:tooltip id="multiWarning" attached="false" showEvent="null" followMouse="false" 
    value="#{messages.warning}" />
```

A couple of issues I encountered:

- `showEvent="null"` is needed to suppress the default trigger (`mouseenter`) from firing, which displayed the tooltip when my cursor entered the enclosing panel
- `followMouse="false"` is needed so we can attach the tooltip to row that fired the show event (note the parameter to the `show` call above).
- If you want to show the tooltip for every row, you can leave the `if` check out of the `onrowmouseover` event, of course.
- I tried to do this with a `<rich:componentControl />` but was unable to pass the event parameter to the `show` function.